# How to embed Qlik App/Sheet on the website

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to embed Qlik `app/sheet` on my website. There are `apps` on the Qlik, and the `apps` contains the `sheets`, which I want to embed for showing to website visitors/user. But users don't have access of Qlik, so I need to embed with some kind of authentication by code.

Before going on the code, I have following things created on the Qlik Management Console (QMC):

1. `Tenant` host
2. Added my domain in the `Content Security Policy` section and selected `frame-ancestors` in the `Directive`
3. `Web Integration Id` created in `Web Integration Configuration` section
4. `Client Id and secret` created in `OAuth` section
5. `Public key, Private` key created by following this article: [Create Signed Tokens for JWT Authorization](https://qlik.dev/authenticate/jwt/create-signed-tokens-for-jwt-authorization/)
6. After following above article, I also have `Issuer, Key ID` which I setup in the `Identity Provider` section

**Following is my usecase**

User first select an `app` from the dropdown, this list populated through the following API:

```
GET https://QLIK-TENANT/api/v1/items?resourceType=app
Header: Bearer <token generated with OAuth Client id and secret>
```

And it is working.

After that I need to show another dropdown for all the `sheets` of the selected `app`. But I am unable to fetch the list of sheets. I checked there is no REST API which can give me `sheets` by an `app`.

**Question 1:** How can I get sheet list of the app? I also plan to list the `sheets` using below JS code, but that is also not working.

Once user select app and sheet, then click on a button to Render sheet, and it should render that sheet on the webpage.

I tried using below piece of code (enigma js), referenced from here: [Handle sheets in iframes with enigma.js](https://qlik.dev/embed/iframe/customize/handle-sheets-in-iframes-with-enigma/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/enigma.js/enigma.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="message"></div>
        <iframe id="qlik_frame" style="border:none;width:100%;height:900px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // CONFIGURATION
        const TENANT = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.qlikcloud.com";
        const JWTENDPOINT = "https://example.com/api/v1/qlik/jwtToken"; // this endpoint create a JWT token using passed data and the private key mentioned in point #6 above
        const WEBINTEGRATIONID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // mentioned in point #3 above
        const APPID = "411111e0-36f8-4e6d-b25d-f0xxxxxxxxca"; // got using the REST API mentioned above
        const IDENTITY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // An arbitrary string to establish a separate session state.

        // MAIN
        (async function main() {
            const isLoggedIn = await qlikLogin();
            const qcsHeaders = await getQCSHeaders();
            const [session, enigmaApp] = await connectEnigma(qcsHeaders, APPID, IDENTITY);

            handleDisconnect(session);
            const theme = await getTheme(enigmaApp);
            const spaceId = (await getApp(APPID)).spaceId;
            const spaceType = await getSpaceType(spaceId);
            const sheets = await getSheetList(enigmaApp, spaceType);

            renderSingleIframe("qlik_frame", APPID, sheets[0].qInfo.qId, theme, IDENTITY);
        })();

        // LOGIN
        async function qlikLogin() {
            const loggedIn = await checkLoggedIn();
            if (loggedIn.status !== 200) {
                const $jwtPostData = {
                    kid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // mentioned in point #6 above
                    iss: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.qlikcloud.com", 
                    name: "?????????" // what it should be????
                };
                const tokenRes = await (await getJWTToken(JWTENDPOINT, $jwtPostData));
                const loginRes = await jwtLogin(tokenRes.body);

                if (loginRes.status != 200) {
                    const message = "Something went wrong while logging in.";
                    throw new Error(message);
                }
                const recheckLoggedIn = await checkLoggedIn();
                if (recheckLoggedIn.status !== 200) {
                    const message = "Third-party cookies are not enabled in your browser settings and/or browser mode.";
                    throw new Error(message);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        async function checkLoggedIn() {
            return await fetch(`https://${TENANT}/api/v1/users/me`, {
                mode: "cors",
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "qlik-web-integration-id": WEBINTEGRATIONID
                },
            })
        }

        // Get Method the JWT and use it to obtain Qlik Cloud session cookie.
        async function getJWTToken(jwtEndpoint, payloadData) {
            try {
                // Define the headers for the request, including the content type
                const headers = new Headers({
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                });

                // Create a request object with the specified method, headers, and body
                const requestOptions = {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: headers,
                    mode: "cors",
                    body: JSON.stringify(payloadData), // Convert payloadData to JSON
                };

                // Use the fetch function to make a POST request to the specified endpoint
                const response = await fetch(jwtEndpoint, requestOptions);

                // Check if the response status code indicates success (e.g., 200 OK)
                if (response.ok) {
                    // Parse the response body as JSON, assuming it contains the JWT
                    const jwtData = await response.json();
                    return jwtData; // Return the JWT data
                } else {
                    // Handle HTTP error responses here if needed
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the fetch request
                console.error("Error fetching JWT:", error);
                throw error;
            }
        }

        async function jwtLogin(token) {
            const authHeader = `Bearer ${token}`;
            return await fetch(`https://${TENANT}/login/jwt-session?qlik-web-integration-id=${WEBINTEGRATIONID}`, {
                credentials: "include",
                mode: "cors",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": authHeader,
                    "qlik-web-integration-id": WEBINTEGRATIONID
                },
            })
        }

        async function getQCSHeaders() {
            const response = await fetch(`https://${TENANT}/api/v1/csrf-token`, {
                mode: "cors",
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "qlik-web-integration-id": WEBINTEGRATIONID
                },
            })

            const csrfToken = new Map(response.headers).get("qlik-csrf-token");
            return {
                "qlik-web-integration-id": WEBINTEGRATIONID,
                "qlik-csrf-token": csrfToken,
            };
        }

        // ENIGMA ENGINE CONNECTION
        async function connectEnigma(qcsHeaders, appId, identity) {
            const [session, app] = await getEnigmaSessionAndApp(appId, qcsHeaders, identity);
            return [session, app];
        }

        async function getEnigmaSessionAndApp(appId, headers, identity) {
            const params = Object.keys(headers)
                .map((key) => `${key}=${headers[key]}`)
                .join("&");

            return (async () => {
                const schema = await (await fetch("https://unpkg.com/enigma.js@2.7.0/schemas/12.612.0.json")).json();

                try {
                    return await createEnigmaAppSession(schema, appId, identity, params);
                } catch {
                    // If the socket is closed immediately following the connection this
                    // could be due to an edge-case race condition where the newly created
                    // user does not yet have access to the app due to access control propagation.
                    // This bit of code will make another attempt after a 1.5 seconds.
                    const waitSecond = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500));
                    try {
                        return await createEnigmaAppSession(schema, appId, identity, params);
                    } catch (e) {
                        throw new Error(e);
                    }
                }
            })();
        }

        async function createEnigmaAppSession(schema, appId, identity, params) {
            const session = enigma.create({
                schema,
                url: `wss://${TENANT}/app/${appId}/identity/${identity}?${params}`,
                createSocket: url => new WebSocket(`wss://${TENANT}/app/${appId}/identity/${identity}?${params}`),
            });

            const enigmaGlobal = await session.open();
            const enigmaApp = await enigmaGlobal.openDoc(appId);
            return [session, enigmaApp];
        }

        // HANDLE ENGINE SESSION CLOSURE
        function handleDisconnect(session) {
            session.on("closed", () => {
                console.log("Due to inactivity or loss of connection, this session has ended.");
            });

            session.on("suspended", () => {
                console.log("Due to loss of connection, this session has been suspended.");
            });

            window.addEventListener("offline", () => {
                session.close();
            });
        }

        // GET QLIK APP (FOR SPACE ID)
        async function getApp(appId) {
            var url = new URL(`https://${TENANT}/api/v1/items?resourceType=app&resourceId=${appId}`);
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: "GET",
                mode: "cors",
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "qlik-web-integration-id": WEBINTEGRATIONID,
                },
            })
            responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson.data[0];
        }

        // GET SPACE (FOR SPACE TYPE)
        async function getSpaceType(spaceId) {
            var url = new URL(`https://${TENANT}/api/v1/spaces/${spaceId}`);
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: "GET",
                mode: "cors",
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "qlik-web-integration-id": WEBINTEGRATIONID,
                },
            })
            responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson.type;
        }

        // GET THEME
        async function getTheme(enigmaApp) {
            const createAppProps = await enigmaApp.createSessionObject({
                qInfo: {
                    qId: "AppPropsList",
                    qType: "AppPropsList"
                },
                qAppObjectListDef: {
                    qType: "appprops",
                    qData: {
                        theme: "/theme"
                    }
                }
            });
            const appProps = await enigmaApp.getObject("AppPropsList");
            const appPropsLayout = await appProps.getLayout();
            const theme = appPropsLayout.qAppObjectList.qItems[0].qData.theme;
            return theme;
        }

        // GET SHEETS (WITH TYPE ADDED, E.G., BASE, COMMUNITY, PRIVATE)
        async function getSheetList(app, spaceType) {
            var sheets = await app.getObjects({
                "qOptions": {
                    "qTypes": [
                        "sheet"
                    ],
                    "qIncludeSessionObjects": false,
                    "qData": {}
                }
            })
            sheetsIncludingType = [];
            for await (const sheet of sheets) {
                var pushSheet = true;
                const sheetObject = await app.getObject(sheet.qInfo.qId);
                const sheetLayout = await sheetObject.getLayout();
                var isManaged = spaceType === "managed";
                var sheetTypeEnum = 1;
                var approved = sheet.qMeta.approved;
                var published = sheet.qMeta.published;
                const sheetTypeEnums = {
                    1: "Base",
                    2: "Community",
                    3: "Private"
                };
                if (!approved && !published) {
                    sheetTypeEnum = 3;
                } else if (!approved && published) {
                    if (isManaged) {
                        sheetTypeEnum = 2;
                    }
                }
                const sheetTypeObject = {
                    "sheetType": sheetTypeEnums[sheetTypeEnum],
                    "sheetTypeEnum": sheetTypeEnum
                };
                const mergedObject = {
                    ...sheetLayout,
                    ...sheetTypeObject
                };
                sheetsIncludingType.push(mergedObject)
            }
            sheetsIncludingType.sort((a, b) => (a.sheetTypeEnum - b.sheetTypeEnum || a.rank - b.rank))
            return sheetsIncludingType;
        }

        // HELPER FUNCTION TO GENERATE IFRAME
        function renderSingleIframe(frameId, appId, sheetId, theme, identity) {
            const frameUrl = `https://${TENANT}/single/?appid=${appId}&sheet=${sheetId}&theme=${theme}&identity=${identity}&opt=ctxmenu,currsel`;
            document.getElementById(frameId).setAttribute("src", frameUrl);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I tried to run, it is not working and returned following `JS` error in console, related to `Socket`:

[image]

Following is the network logs when I tried to run this code: [image]

**Question 2:** How to embed `sheet/app`? In above code, Am I doing something wrong? Or if there are any other way to embed, please suggest me. Because I doubt, that it will need to create a lot of resources on the `QMC`. So there should be some `API`, to authenticate user, get token and use token to get embed code for the `sheet`.

Please help me. Any suggestion will also be helpful.

**EDIT:** I also asked same question on Qlik Community here: https://community.qlik.com/t5/Integration-Extension-APIs/How-to-embed-Qlik-App-Sheet-on-the-website/m-p/2424524#M20033
One bro suggested to go with [Qlik-embed](https://qlik.dev/embed/qlik-embed/why-qlik-embed/), but still there are some limitations.

Thank you

Comment: for the people who are still struggling, can check and follow the steps mentioned here: https://community.qlik.com/t5/Member-Articles/Enhanced-Guide-Embedding-Qlik-Cloud-Content-with-JWT/tac-p/2433942#M2144